# Flip View for 2.2.1 iPhone SDk

Tags: iphone

I have an App that works great in 3.1.2, yet when I revert to 2.2.1 my method to flip the view doesn't work, using the following code:

```
-(IBAction)infoButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle:nil];

    second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

I get the following error (http://screencast.com/t/YTJlYTgz). Thoughts on how I can fix this easily?

Answer (score 2):

`modalTransitionStyle` is only available for 3.0+.  If you want to have a similar transition you will have to create the animation transition yourself.  Take a look at the following UIView function

`+ (void)setAnimationTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransition)transition forView:(UIView *)view cache:(BOOL)cache`